# Primefaces lazy loading datatable and filter form outside of table

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable

As said in the title. Is it possible to do this?

I would like to have for instance filter form in dialog, and displayed it on demand.

I suppose it would be possible with filteredValue option, but as i understand that is not used with lazy loading.

I would appreciate any advice.

Comment: There is a duplicate of this but I cannot find it. Effectively this is not to difficult. Start with trying to use a class level field from outside the load and use it inside  the load method when filtering. Then try setting that field via EL from an input outside the datatable and after setting that field explicitly, call the datatable widgetVar `.filter()` javascript method to actually filter it

Comment: I dont't think i understand this part: "Start with trying to use a class level field from outside the load". First what would the field represent? The search criteria? Does that mean that i would need to have multiple fields like that for multiple filter conditions. And if so how do i map that field to entity properties, and or datatable? Other thing, what is outside load? Does that mean outside datatable? For instance in my search form?